# HTTPS Volley Invalid header проблема

Tags: java, android, ssl, openssl

Предисловие: если не знаете точного ответа, то дайте совет как можно это сделать по другому или как попробовать проверить

Я попробовал уже несколько разных способов имплементировать `Volley` ssl , но безуспешно . Постоянно получаю вот такую ошибку. Поэтому мне кажется, что проблема не в коде

```
 ResponseJsonString = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
                      <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
                      <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
                      <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
                      <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
                      </BODY></HTML>
```

Вот так выглядит код

Создаю `Volley` очередь

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new SslHurlStuck(SslUtils.KEYSTORE, SslUtils.PASSWORD_SSL, this));
```

Вот `SslHurlStuck` класс

```
package utils.ssl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import utils.global.AppUtils;


public class SslHurlStuck extends HurlStack
{
private final static String TAG = SslHurlStuck.class.getSimpleName();

private String mTrustStoreAssetName;
private String mTrustStorePassword;
private Context mContext;

public SslHurlStuck(final String iTrustStoreAssetName, final String iTrustStorePassword, Context iContext)
{
    super();

    mTrustStoreAssetName = iTrustStoreAssetName;
    mTrustStorePassword = iTrustStorePassword;
    mContext = iContext;
}

@Override
protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException
{
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {
        urlConnection = new PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory(mContext).createHttpsURLConnection(url.toString(), mTrustStoreAssetName, mTrustStorePassword);
    }
    catch (Throwable iThrowable)
    {
        AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, iThrowable.getMessage());
    }

    return urlConnection;
}
}
```

Вот `PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory`  класс

```
package utils.ssl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

 import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import utils.global.AppUtils;
import webServices.global.RequestStringBuilder;


public class PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory
{
private final static String TAG = PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context mContext;

public PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory(Context iContext)
{
    mContext = iContext;
}

HttpsURLConnection createHttpsURLConnection(String urlString, final String iTrustStoreAssetName, final String iTrustStorePassword) throws Throwable
{
    // Initialize the trust manager factory instance with our trust store
    // as source of certificate authorities and trust material.
    KeyStore trustStore = new TrustStoreFactory(iTrustStoreAssetName, iTrustStorePassword, mContext).createTrustStore();
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

    // Initialize the SSL context.
    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers());
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SslUtils.PROTOCOL_TLS);
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    // Create the https URL connection.
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());

    return urlConnection;
}

// Let's assume your server app is hosting inside a server machine
// which has a server certificate in which "Issued to" is "localhost",for example.
// Then, inside verify method you can verify "localhost".
// If not, you can temporarily return true
private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier()
{
    return new HostnameVerifier()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
        {
            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

            String localHost = SslUtils.SSL_LOCAL_HOST_DEV;

            if (RequestStringBuilder.isEnvironmentProd())
            {
                localHost = SslUtils.SSL_LOCAL_HOST_PROD;
            }

            return hv.verify(localHost, session);
            //              return hv.verify("localhost", session);
            //              return true;
        }
    };
}

private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers)
{
    final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

    final X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager()
    {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (certs != null && certs.length > 0)
                {
                    for (X509Certificate cer : certs)
                    {
                        cer.checkValidity();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            }
            catch (CertificateException e)
            {
                AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, "checkClientTrusted" + e.toString());
            }
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (certs != null && certs.length > 0)
                {
                    for (X509Certificate cer : certs)
                    {
                        cer.checkValidity();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            }
            catch (CertificateException e)
            {
                AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, "checkServerTrusted" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    return new TrustManager[] {x509TrustManager};
}
}
```

вот `TrustStoreFactory` класс

```
public class TrustStoreFactory
{
private String mTrustStoreAssetName;
private String mTrustStorePassword;

private Context mContext;

public TrustStoreFactory(final String iTrustStoreAssetName, final String iTrustStorePassword, final Context iContext)
{
    mTrustStoreAssetName = iTrustStoreAssetName;
    mTrustStorePassword = iTrustStorePassword;
    mContext = iContext;
}

KeyStore createTrustStore() throws Throwable
{
    // Retrieve the trust store file from the assets.
    InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(mTrustStoreAssetName);

    try
    {
        // Create a key store with the retrieved input stream.
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(SslUtils.KEYSTORE_EXTENSION_BKS);

        trustStore.load(inputStream, mTrustStorePassword.toCharArray());

        return trustStore;
    }
    finally
    {
            inputStream.close();
    }
}
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

В моем `keystore` 2 сертификата, я предполагал , что может проблема в последовательности добавления их в `keystore` , пробовал добавлять их в разной последовательности, но не помагает

Как я говорил, я не думаю , что проблема в коде, мне кажется, что проблема в сертификатах , но я не знаю как это проверить

И что интересно, что на iOS это работает, но там он просто получает ответ с сервера из него достает сертификат из сертификата `public key` и сравнивает его с `public key` сертификата который у него сохранен локально.

То есть вместо того, чтоб добавлять эти сертификаты в `keystore` как в андроиде он просто проверяет `public key`. Почему в андроиде так усложнено ...

Если есть вопросы говорите

Comment: Судя по ошибке "HTTP Error 400", SSL отрабатывает и тут вообще ни при чем. Вопрос можно закрыть с формулировкой "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой".

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну я не совсем уверен, так как без SSL имплементации это работало нормально, как только я добавил SSL стала вот такая проблема. Хотя судя по имплементации видно, что никакого кода который бы как то влиял за хедеры в запросе нет... Значит все таки эта имплементация как то внутри что то делает... Понимаете, что я имеею ввиду?

Comment: Только если на бэкенде SSL запросы обрабатываются иначе, чем обычные. Но к клиенту это не имеет никакого отношения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я просто удалил хедер `Content-Type` с его значением из запроса и все заработало. Не знаю с чем это связано

Вот тут нашел это решение

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739276/android-volley-gives-me-400-error

Comment: А Вы этот заголовок вводили с клавиатуры или копипастили - может какой непечатный символ закрался?

Comment: @woesss Вы имеете ввиду `Content-Type` ? Я уже и не помню как я его написал...